# Why is Resident Set Size (RSS) much much bigger than heap occupation for my java application?

Tags: java, memory-management

It is an spring boot web application and when access peak arrives the RSS will increase, and after that heap shrinks (System.gc() is called every minute) but RSS still remains huge:

$ top |grep 8544
 8544 userA       20   0 9290m **2.3g** 9548 S  0.3  2.4 470:02.80 java

while the heap is only **160M** shown by jmap.

When checking /proc/8544/smaps, I found:

```html
00601000-006ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
Size:                820 kB
Rss:                 748 kB
Pss:                 748 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:       748 kB
Referenced:          748 kB
Anonymous:           748 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
760000000-78aaa0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:             699008 kB
Rss:              699008 kB
Pss:              699008 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:    699008 kB
Referenced:       699008 kB
Anonymous:        699008 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
78aaa0000-7e0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:            1398144 kB
Rss:             1398140 kB
Pss:             1398140 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:   1398140 kB
Referenced:      1398140 kB
Anonymous:       1398140 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

There are about 300 threads in the process and stack frame is size of 1M.
But still the gap between RSS and really used memory is too big.
So please help to advice what may be going on here or how I can find more hints.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll give you two advices: a) Don't call `System.gc();`, it's not meant to be called (especially by you) and b) Don't worry about the memory unless it is an actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, now I understand System.gc() helps nothing. While for the memory cost, I am still wondering what is going on...